# How can I call a controller method from view page?

Tags: codeigniter

I am beginner in Codeigniter. I created simple login page with session. I Logged in with correct login details.Now I showing view page.

My Question is how can I set logout. And how can i call controller method again from view page?

I created logout method also.

My Controller Page:

```
//load database libray manually
$this->load->database();
$this->load->model('L_Model');
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->library('session');
//load Model


}

public function check_login(){   
  $data['error']="";
  if($this->input->post('email') && $this->input->post('pass')){
    $email=$this->input->post('email');
    $pass=$this->input->post('pass');
    $user_count=$this->L_Model->check_user($email,$pass);
    if($user_count==0){
      $data['error']="<h4 style='color:red;text-align:center'>Invalid user details</h4>";
    }else{
      $this->session->set_userdata('email', $email);
      redirect('Login/dash');
    }
  }else{
    $data['error']="<h4 style='color:red;text-align:center'>Enter required details</h4>";
  }
 $this->load->view('m-login',$data);
}

public function dash(){
  if(!$this->session->userdata('email')){
     $data['error']="<h4 style='color:red;text-align:center;'>Please login</h4>";
     $this->load->view('m-login',$data);
  }else{
     $this->load->view('dashboard');
  }
}

public function logout(){
 $this->session->unset_userdata('email');   
 $this->load->view('m-login');
}
```

}
?>
   My View Page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>CSS Website Layout</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
     .header,.footer,.menu {
       background-color: #f1f1f1;
       padding: 15px;
       text-align: center;
      }
     .menu{
     margin-top:20px;
     }

    </style>
     </head>
     <body>
     <div class="header">
       <h3>Welcome to your dashboard...<?=$this->session->userdata('email');?> 
      </h3>
    </div>
     <div class="menu">
       demo
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you will do just route to your logout method e.g `redirect(base_url(login/logout));` where login is the controller and logout is the method for session clearing in codeigniter e.g `$this->session->sess_destroy()` or `session_destroy();` but before you can do this make sure you have load codigniter session library like this `$this->load->library('session');`.
To redirect back to login page, after you clear all the session data use this to redirect back to login page as redirect(base_url('login'));

Code for logout is

```php
public function logout () {
     $this->load->library('session');
     $this->session->sess_destroy();
     redirect(base_url('login'));

}
```

In you html do this

```php
<div><a href="<?php echo base_url('login/logout');?>">Logout</a></div>
```

I hope this helped you else call my attention

Comment: Enjoy I am happy it works for you. But remember to secure your auth system because what you posted here is not really looking secured.

Comment: Thank you- I have one more doubt.

My local project is id passing like blow.. 

http://localhost/thiru/CodeIgniter/Project1/updata?id=31

How can i pass my query string  ilke that http://localhost/thiru/CodeIgniter/Project1/updata/31

Comment: @ThirumalaiKarthi you can [**accept an answer**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) by clicking the tick mark on the left. You're free to switch later when a better answer comes along. On Stack Exchange sites the way to say **thank you** is to [upvote helpful answers and accept the most helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I was a little bit busy on a project. Concerning your question, If the Codeigniter is your controller while project1 is your method in the  localhost/thiru/CodeIgniter/Project1/updata/31 you provided here, go ahead to load your url that way and use ``$id = $this->uri->segment(4)`` in your controller to get the id i.e 31. I hope this will help you else call my attention

Comment: @Chibueze Agwu ,Sorry for discussing again.. I am beginner in codeigniter..First I called  a controller like that <a href='updata?id=".$row->id."' style='text-decoration:none'>Edit</a>.

Now i changed to <a href='updata/".$row->id."' style='text-decoration:none'>Edit</a>  and my controller page using $id = $this->uri->segment(3) .

Its working ...This is correct way or not?

Comment: Normally I don't like using short breaking url in my anchor because this does not really work in some area. So I prefer including the base_url function to my url to point to the http request well. Use this instead I think it will be the best <a href="<?php echo base_url('your_controller/updata/'.$row->id);?>">Edit</a>. I think this will work for you and more better to point well.